# How to set a max value for individual cells in a column, where if the actual number would have been higher, it reverts to the max value?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a column of scores, where I want to set the maximum score anyone can receive to 1000 points.  It is possible to get more points than 1000 but that is the max.
How do I set up so that my Google Sheet automatically force changes to any scores that are over 1000 to 1000?

Comment: Welcome! What about `=MIN(1000, SUM(<range_of_points>))`?

Comment: with which formula do you now get the values ​​of the "score" column?

Comment: Welcome. Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well. You can even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) the answer. If you don't have enough reputation, your upvote will show up later, once you reach [enough reputation points](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up).

Comment: Currently using =B1*50, then pulling down the bottom corner of the cell to complete the rest.  Each point a participant has is * 50 to get a score.  But they could get more than 40 points.  40 *50=1000.  Thus the need for the limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that cells `B2:B` contain the various scores, you will need a new column with formula in row 2:

```
= index (if (B2:B > 1000,1000, B2:B))
```

This will complete the calculations for the whole column.

It is also possible to modify column `B` in this sense, if it already contains its own calculation.

**EDIT**: you said "Currently using =B1*50"

so the formula coud be:

```
= index (if (B1*50 > 1000,1000, B1*50))
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the awesome suggestions!  With try them out now and report back.  Thanks

Comment: This worked perfectly!   Thanks.